# Values not split. "not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)" when going through my text file line by line

Tags: python

```
def player_login():

    username = ""
    new = "0"

    while new not in ('1', '2'):
        print("Type 1 to Login")
        print("Type 2 to Register")
        new = input("")

    if new == '1':
        login_username = input('username: ')
        login_password = input('password: ')
        found_username = False

        with open('user_database.txt', 'r') as password_file:
            for line in password_file:
                username, password = line.strip().split(':')

                if login_username == username:
                    found_username = True
                    if login_password == password:
                        print('success!')
                    else:
                        print('login failure!')
                    break

        username = login_username
        if not found_username:
            print('username invalid')
    if new == '2':
        #code continues
player login()
```

This is the error message I get:

line 18, in player_login

username, password = line.strip().split(':')

ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)

Its weird because this code used to work until I switched from PyCharm to VSC and I cannot figure out the problem. Any help is appreciated.

This is my text file if it helps:

```
asdaasda:asdaasda
asdfasdf:asdfasdf
hellohi:hellohi
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`user_database.txt` has some line that is missing `:` (perhaps an empty line)

A simple fix is often to skip blank lines

```py
    ...
    for line in fh:
        if not line:
            continue
        ...
```

It's also often helpful to `enumerate()` to report bad lines

```py
for lineno, line in enumerate(fh, 1):
    ...
    if (<some validations fails>):
        print(f"bad line {lineno}: {line}")  # raise ValueError? to taste
```

Answer (score 1):

One of the lines of the file does not have a `:` as @ti7 says. Some further debug steps.

```
for i, line in enumerate(password_file):
    try:
        username, password = line.strip().split(':')
    except ValueError as e:
        print(i, line)
```

The try except will now print out the line number and the text of any offending lines.